# Download images from url that is stored in .txt file?

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.6 on Windows 10, I want to download images so that their urls are stored in `1.txt` file.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import shutil

file_image_url = open("test.txt","r")
while True:
    image_url = file_image_url.readline()
    filename = image_url.split("/")[-1]
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream = True)
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    with open(filename,'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

but when I run the code above it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "download_pictures.py", line 10, in <module>
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '03.jpg\n'
```

`test.txt` contains:

```
https://mysite/images/03.jpg
https://mysite/images/26.jpg
https://mysite/images/34.jpg
```

When I tried to put just one single URL on `test.txt`, it works and downloaded the picture,
but I need to download several images.

Comment: ``image_url = file_image_url.readline().strip()``

Comment: @MikeScotty you are a legend man, thanks ..

Comment: @MikeScotty how can i put your answer is the correct one ?

Comment: You can't, because it's a comment, not an answer. Feel free to accept one of the other answers that explain the issue in more detail ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`f.readline()` reads a single line from the file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects); a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

You are passing this `filename`(with `\n`) to `open` function(hence the `OSError`). So you need to call `strip()` on `filename` before passing into `open`.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename has the new line character (`\n`) in it, remove that when you’re parsing for the filename and it should fix your issue. It’s working when you only have one file path in the txt file because there is only one line.